# sizewithAttributes not returning the correct height for uilabels

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

I am trying to calculate the correct height of uilabels in a uitableview with the sizewithattributes method. But the height that it is returning is well below what it should be, the labels text is cut off and outputting the height returned from textwithattributes to the console shows heights of around 20 - 40 even for full paragraphs of text. I have set my font size and font to be the same as the uilabel in the attributes section of the method and I have the line break mode set to wordwrap for the uilabel. Thanks in Advance

Code:`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(  NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSDictionary *message =  self.messages[indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"%lu", (long)indexPath.row);
    UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:20000];
    UILabel *messageContent = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:10000];
    UIImageView *image = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:30000];
    UIButton *replyButton = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:40000];
    replyButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    messageContent.text = [message objectForKey:@"messageContent"];
    NSString *content = [message objectForKey:@"messageContent"];
    NSLog(@"Message: %@", content);

    NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:17.0f]};
    // NSString class method: boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context is
    // available only on ios7.0 sdk.
    CGRect rect = [content boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(10000, MAXFLOAT)
                                              options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                           attributes:attributes
                                              context:nil];

    CGFloat height = ceilf(rect.size.height);
    CGFloat width  = ceilf(rect.size.width);
    messageContent.frame = CGRectMake(40, 126, width, height);


    NSLog(@"Height:%f", messageContent.frame.size.height);
    NSLog(@"y: %f", messageContent.frame.origin.y);
    NSLog(@"estimated height: %f", height);




    nameLabel.text = [message objectForKey:@"senderName"];

    UIImage *senderPic = self.senderPictures[indexPath.row];
    image.image = senderPic;
    image.layer.cornerRadius = 27.0;
    image.layer.masksToBounds = YES;





    return cell;
}
`
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in line:

```
//[content boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(10000, MAXFLOAT)
```

you specified 100000 pt as a width of your text, I don't know how many characters is your `content` string contain but I believe you can easy display it in one or two line if your line is 10000 pt long.

The better way to do it is add the text to the label read size of it and change label frame if needed:

```
CGSize labelSize = [self.messageContent.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:self.messageContent.font.pointSize]}];
```

Comment: This still does not solve the problem :(, it still returns the same values as before

Comment: Have you try sizeWithAttributes: ?

Comment: Yes, I put exactly what you wrote above but the problem remains the same

Comment: @user2489946 see edited post and check out the value of width and height from labelSize

Comment: There was little change, the height increased by one

Comment: This method should get you a size you need to contain the text in the label.

Comment: It doesnt, i have tried this on a uilabel outside of a uitableview, with different font sizes, font types etc and every time it returns a value that is much too small for the text that the label contains

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43849/discussion-between-user2489946-and-greg)